# how to make thumbnail image from video file in laravel?

Tags: laravel, video

I am using videoThumnail class in packagist.org.

```
VideoThumbnail::createThumbnail(public_path('uploaded_video/oceans.mp4'), public_path('cover_images'),'movie.jpg', 2, 1920, 1080);
```

but it is not saving image in thumnail path.
please help me.

Comment: Is there video processing software on the server?

Comment: yes, I am using goddady. not software. I am building website in laravel.

Comment: You cannot do without FFMpeg and / or similar video processing software.